# PHP Soap Client: SoapFault - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I want to access some web service. I use PHP SoapClient like this:

```
$user_key = "myKey";

    $service = new SoapClient('https://myadress.xsd',array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2
    ));

    $sid = $service->Zaloguj($user_key);`
```

After that i get Exception "SoapFault: Internal Server Error"

When i call

`$service->__getFunctions()`
    i get list

```
ZalogujResponse Zaloguj(Zaloguj $parameters)
```

When i change parameter

```
"soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1
```

i get other error:

`Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xm`

i tried many combination like:

```
$params =  new stdClass();
$params->key = $user_key;
$sid = $service->Zaloguj($params);
```

and i get same error
    `"SoapFault: Internal Server Error"`